# Redis Cluster Docker Compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, redis-cluster

I'm struggling to create a Docker Compose to create a Redis Cluster. I saw that there is a Redis Cluster image from Bitnami, I tried but it my Spring Boot App cannot connect to it due to the below error:
[image]

I tried another approach is to create 2 Redis instances master-slave and I can connect to it. Now I'm trying to create 6 Redis Instances and later create a Redis Cluster with 3 master and 3 slaves with the following command:

```
redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:6380 127.0.0.1:6381 \
127.0.0.1:6382 127.0.0.1:6383 127.0.0.1:6384 127.0.0.1:6385 --cluster-replicas 1
```

But when I executed the command it said that

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6380: Connection refused
```

Below is my current Docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  redis-node-0:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-0
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    command: ["redis-server","--appendonly yes","--cluster-enabled yes","--cluster-node-timeout 5000"]
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-0:/redis/data

  redis-node-1:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-1
    ports:
      - "6381:6379"
    command: ["redis-server","--appendonly yes","--cluster-enabled yes","--cluster-node-timeout 5000"]  
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-1:/redis/data

  redis-node-2:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-2
    ports:
      - "6382:6379"
    command: ["redis-server","--appendonly yes","--cluster-enabled yes","--cluster-node-timeout 5000"]
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-2:/redis/data

  redis-node-3:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-3
    ports:
      - "6383:6379"
    command: ["redis-server","--appendonly yes","--cluster-enabled yes","--cluster-node-timeout 5000"]
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-3:/redis/data

  redis-node-4:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-4
    ports:
      - "6384:6379"
    command: ["redis-server","--appendonly yes","--cluster-enabled yes","--cluster-node-timeout 5000"]
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-4:/redis/data

  redis-node-5:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-5
    ports:
      - "6385:6379"
    command: ["redis-server","--appendonly yes","--cluster-enabled yes","--cluster-node-timeout 5000"]
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-5:/redis/data


networks: 
  default:
    name: overlay
volumes:
  redis-cluster_data-0:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-1:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-2:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-3:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-4:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-5:
    driver: local
```

I'm totally new to Both Docker and Redis, I'm learning so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are using the default redis image which uses 6379 port as default. So your port config should be for node 0 like 6380:6379,  for node 1 6381:6379 and so on. You can try that and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @Shawrup, I updated the docker-compose and also change the ip when creating the cluster but I faced this error
[ERR] Node 192.168.32.2:6379 is not configured as a cluster node.

Comment: I am guessing that you did not configured redis to support clustering. you need to update the redis.conf files. You can find the docs here https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial . Or you can use this https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yml this seems have am image with cluster support built in.

Comment: I have added a *command* tag, and successfully create a Redis Cluster. If you have knowledge about connecting from Spring Boot App to Redis Cluster, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm have you solved it?

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this is not obvious, because Redis Cluster doesn't easily work with Docker bridge networking. The simplest way to setup a single-node cluster is to cheat and bind it to 127.0.0.1:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis-single-node-cluster:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS=0'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR=yes'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_DYNAMIC_IPS=no'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_ANNOUNCE_IP=127.0.0.1'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

You can then connect to it with this Spring Boot config:

```
spring:
  redis:
    cluster:
      nodes: [localhost:6379]
    ssl: false
```

If you want to setup multiple nodes, you'll have to create a custom network and assign static IPs. You'll probably also have to set `network_mode: host`.